# Rename a file with github api?

Tags: rename, github-api

I thought that the [update file](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#update-a-file) method of the Github API could be used to rename a file (by providing the new path as parameter) but it does not seem to work.

The only way to rename is to delete the file and to create a similar one with the new name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I thought that the update file method of the Github API could be used to rename a file (by providing the new path as parameter) but it does not seem to work.

There's no way to rename a file with a single request to the API.

> The only way to rename is to delete the file and to create a similar one with the new name?

That's one way, but the downside is that you get two commits in the history (one for the delete, and one for the create).

A different way is to use the low-level Git API:

https://developer.github.com/v3/git/

With that, you can modify the tree entry containing the blob to list it under a different name, then create a new commit for that tree, and finally update the branch to point to that new commit. The whole process requires more API requests, but you get a single commit for the rename.

Comment: [Here](http://www.levibotelho.com/development/commit-a-file-with-the-github-api/) is a very nice article to complete this answer.

Comment: @lvan Zuzak, Thank for explain the process. Could you please provide github rest api list step by step to complete rename file so it more helpful. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I found this article useful: [Renaming files using the GitHub api](https://medium.com/@obodley/renaming-a-file-using-the-git-api-fed1e6f04188) but it didn't work for me completely. It was duplicating files.
Since deleting files is available just through changing the tree I came up with such replacement of the tree in step 3 of that article:

```
{
    "base_tree": "{yourbaseTreeSHA}",
    "tree": [
      {
        "path": "archive/TF/service/DEV/service_SVCAAA03v3DEV.tf',
        "mode": "100644",
        "type": "blob",
        "sha": "{yourFileTreeSHA}"",
      },
      {
        "path": "TF/service/DEV/service_SVCAAA03v3DEV.tf",
        "mode": "100644",
        "type": "blob",
        "sha": null,
      }
    ],
  }
```

and it really does the trick.
So to have the rename/move of the file done you need to do 5 calls to GitHub API but the result is awesome:
[view of the commit on github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2ZYW.png)

Answer (score 2):

With the help of the following articles, I figured out how to rename a file with Github API.

- [node package: github-api](https://github.com/michael/github/blob/d9e33891bb98dae0dcdabd19342c4388bfc00790/github.js#L780)
- [Commit directly to GitHub via API with Octokit](http://mattgreensmith.net/2013/08/08/commit-directly-to-github-via-api-with-octokit/)
- [Commit a file with the GitHub API](http://www.levibotelho.com/development/commit-a-file-with-the-github-api/)

First, find and store the tree that latest commit.

```
# Gem octokir.rb 4.2.0 and Github API v3
api = Octokit::Client.new(access_token: "")
ref = 'heads/master'
repo = 'repo/name'
master_ref = api.ref repo, ref
last_commit = api.commit(repo, master_ref[:object][:sha])
last_tree = api.tree(repo, last_commit[:sha], recursive: true)
```

Use **The harder way** described in article **Commit a file with the
GitHub API** to create a new tree. Then, do the rename just like the
nodeJs version does and create a new tree based on the below changes.

```
changed_tree = last_tree[:tree].map(&:to_hash).reject { |blob| blob[:type] == 'tree' }
changed_tree.each { |blob| blob[:path] = new_name if blob[:path] == old_name }
changed_tree.each { |blob| blob.delete(:url) && blob.delete(:size) }
new_tree = api.create_tree(repo, changed_tree)
```

Create a new commit then point the HEAD to it.

```
new_commit = api.create_commit(repo, "Rename #{File.basename(old_name)} to #{File.basename(new_name)}", new_tree[:sha], last_commit[:sha])
api.update_ref(repo, ref, new_commit.sha)
```

That's all.

Answer (score 0):

For those who end up here looking for more options, there is a better way to rename a file/folder. Please refer to the below link:
[Rename a file using Azure devops api (should work similar for corresponding github api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pushes/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#rename-a-file)

Works for folder rename as well. There you would need to specify the folder path for new and old using the same payload structure as in the sample request in above link.

Comment: As I checked, the link is for https://dev.azure.com/ instead of GitHub.